# html in app.component.ts in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create an updateable element in my app,

so in my html I have

```
<div>{{example}}</div>
```

then in my app component Ive done this..

```
example: string = `this is some text <br> this is more text`
```

but the output on the site was `this is some text <br> this is more text` so the whole thing was inserted as a string

Thanks

Comment: did you got any error??,can you give plunker link

Comment: @Robert see updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `innerHTML` :

```
<div [innerHTML]="example"></div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-inner-html-demo)**

Comment: see updated question

Comment: yes sorry this worked, I will mark you correct in 4 minutes

Comment: @A61NN5 , Happens , Glad you find it , Happy Coding BTW :) .